# Is there a way to insert a tag into an existing Golang struct?

Tags: go, struct

```
type ECG struct {
       PatientName  string
}

func (ecg *ECG)  AttachXMLTag(s string) {
      
}
```

So the struct would look like this after using it's AttachXMLTag method:

type ECG struct {
PatientName string `xml:"testingtag"`
}

I need this to happen during runtime.

Comment: This is not possible, you cannot change struct tags at runtime. Perhaps the closest you can get to what you want is to create a new struct at runtime with [`reflect.StructOf`](https://pkg.go.dev/reflect@go1.20#StructOf), using the original structs as a "template".

Comment: It's possible to change struct tags at runtime with this library: https://github.com/Ompluscator/dynamic-struct  
He doesn't give an example of how to update the tags

Comment: No it's not possible @MarcDi. What `SetTag` does in that library is only set the builder's fieldConfig's tag, but that will not change the original struct's struct tag. It's working on the same principle as suggested in the first comment, using structof to create a new struct.

Comment: https://go.dev/play/p/VIWMBO_k5Zs @MarcDi

Comment: https://github.com/Ompluscator/dynamic-struct/blob/v1.3.0/builder.go#L192 @MarcDi